# Conditional ploting in Gnuplot using fortran 90

Tags: fortran, gnuplot

i have a truss bridge that i want to draw using fortran 90 and Gnuplot , but the truss elements should change color if the corresponding array element is bigger or smaller than zero

```
open(10,file='plot_2D.plt')
write(10,*) 'set title " truss"'
write(10,*) 'set xrange [0:300]'
write(10,*) 'set yrange [0:40]'
write(10,*) 'set xlabel "x [U]"'
write(10,*) 'set ylabel "y [U]"' 
write(10,*) 'set key noautotitle'        
write(10,*) 'plot "1.txt" if (x(1) > 0 ) {with line 7} else { with line lt 3 } '
write(10,*) 'pause -1 "Hit return to continue"'
close(10)
```

ofcourse i have 1.txt up to 222.txt 
but i just put one here because it is repetitive process
but i dont get any plot , 
what is my mistake ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what exactly you mean by `x(1) > 0` since there is no function x() defined.  Assuming that `x(1)` means `data value in column 1`, then instead of

```
write(10,*) 'plot "1.txt" if (x(1) > 0 ) {with line 7} else { with line lt 3 } '
```

the correct syntax is

```
write(10,*) 'plot "1.txt" using 1:2:($1>0 ? 7 : 3) with lines linecolor variable'
```

Comment: is `1>0 ? 7 : 3` a conditional ternary operator?

Comment: Yes, it is a ternary operator.